# How do we prove that the normal vectors to the sides of a polygon add up to 0?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Given any triangle in the plane, associate to each side an outward pointing
normal vector of the same length as the side. Show that the sum of these three
vectors is always 0.

Comment: What choice : a triangle (your text) or a general polygon (your title) ?

Comment: Sorry, its a triangle. My mistake

Comment: True for polygon also.

Comment: @amitava can you please help prove this? Right now im focusing on the triangle, the contribution would be appreciated

Comment: A rotation should do polygon as well as a triangle.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Note that cyclic vectors parallel to the sides of the triangle (and having the same length as each) sum to zero. Does this tell you anything about the sum of normals with severally equal lengths?

*Elaboration:* Please note that the three normals also determine a (congruent) triangle (since the lengths of the normals are equal to the lengths of the original sides). Draw a diagram to confirm that the orientation of the arrows is cyclic as in the original. Then the result follows.

Comment: [+1} Splendid answer. Maybe, you have to elaborate it a little in order to be well understood.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I still don't understand, however, how can you be sure that the vectors parallel to the sides of the triangle sum to 0? If they are all pointing in he same direction, wouldn't they just compound?....
Sorry, I guess I'm slow, I've been working on this for hours and am just left with scribbles on paper lol

Comment: It suffices to say that if $A_0,A_1,\cdots A_n=A_0$ are the vertices of your polygon (it is not more complicated to consider a polygon than a triangle), numbered in positive orientation, with cyclic numbering, we have $\sum_k \vec{A_kA_{k+1}}=0$. Then calling $R$ the (negatively oriented) $-\pi/2$ rotation, we obtain that the sum of outward normals is zero by applying $R$ to relationship (1) : $\sum_k R(\vec{A_kA_{k+1}})=0.$

Comment: @smaj We always make the assumption that the vectors are cyclic. That is, each starts where the other left off. I've added o my answer. See if it helps.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. I added to the picture. Was that what you had in mind too?

Comment: I'm beginning to understand conceptually and intuitively this makes sense...however, I'm still confused as to how to prove this analytically!
For example, if we let a, b, and c be the sides of the triangle how can I show that the normals to a b and c will add up to 0?
Also, this is a very basic-level multivariable calc question, we've only covered dot product the definition of the vector, angle between vectors, and normals. So simple langugae is appreciated

Comment: @smaj To prove this analytically might be tedious -- you'd get embroiled in coordinates, cosines and all that. Don't get the idea that if there are no symbols, then it's no proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_0, A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n = A_0$ be the vertices of a $n$-gon oriented counterclockwisely and $N_i$ be the outward point vector for edge $A_iA_{i+1}$ for $0 \le i < n$ with length $|A_i A_{i+1}|$.

If one embed $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the map $$p =(x,y) \quad\mapsto\quad \vec{p} = (x,y,0)$$
convince yourself that

$$\vec{N}_i =  (\vec{A}_{i+1}-\vec{A}_i) \times \hat{z}$$

This implies

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \vec{N}_i =
 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\vec{A}_{i+1}-\vec{A}_i) \times \hat{z} 
=  (\vec{A}_{n}-\vec{A}_0) \times \hat{z}  = \vec{0}$$

This phenomenon is not limited to $2$-d. For example, for any polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$, if you associate an outward pointing normal to each face with length proportional to the face area, these outward pointing normals also sum to zero.

Comment: [+1] As usual you bring a precise answer and moreover here a generalization...

Answer (score 1):

Draw a triangle or polygon. Choose a point(vertex) and start traversing clockwise (for example) on the sides. The vectors you get in this process are the vectors whose magnitudes are the length of the sides and direction is the direction of traverse. As you complete traversing you reach to the point from where you started traversing. So you see all the vectors can not be in the same direction so that they will add up to a non zero value. Now this addition will add up to zero by definition of vector addition (as you reached to the same point) . Now vectors normal(outward) to the sides with equal magnitudes are just these vectors rotated 90 degree counterclockwise. As all the vectors rotated by same angle in the same direction ( here it is 90 degree counterclockwise, but could have been any angle in the same direction); the resultant vectors magnitude will remain same. Here the resultant magnitude is zero because earlier also it was zero.

Edit:

(1) For a polygon you need to apply [triangle law of vector addition](https://byjus.com/physics/triangle-law-of-vector-addition/) repeatedly to get the resultant vector. If sides of a polygon is A,B,C,D (in order) then you see $\overrightarrow{\rm A} + \overrightarrow{\rm B} + \overrightarrow{\rm C} + \overrightarrow{\rm D} = (\overrightarrow{\rm A} + \overrightarrow{\rm B}) + \overrightarrow{\rm C} + \overrightarrow{\rm D}$. (here $\overrightarrow{\rm A} + \overrightarrow{\rm B}$ is a vector). Which can be be further written as $( (\overrightarrow{\rm A} + \overrightarrow{\rm B}) + \overrightarrow{\rm C} ) + \overrightarrow{\rm D}$.

Now we see that vector $( (\overrightarrow{\rm A} + \overrightarrow{\rm B}) + \overrightarrow{\rm C} )$ is equal in magnitude but opposite in direction of vector D. So they cancel out.

(2)  Now consider vectors normal to these vectors and outward from the enclosed area. The outward is defined by direction which is rotated 90 degree anticlockwise if you traverse clockwise (or rotated 90 degree clockwise if you traverse anticlockwise). If you consider two adjacent vectors of the polygon say A,B and their normal vectors $A^{'},B^{'}$ then vector $A^{'}+B^{'}$ will be normal to vector $A+B$ and equal in magnitude to $A+B$. Similarly $A^{'}+B^{'}+C^{'}$ will be normal to vector $A+B+C$ but equal in magnitude to $A+B+C$. So vector $A^{'}+B^{'}+C^{'}$ will be equal in magnitude but opposite in direction of vector $D^{'}$ which is normal to vector D. So they will cancel out each other.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense! However can you do this analytically? Conceptually this is great but i want somehting with variables

Comment: @user700010  I guess if you got this as homework and if you write this, you should get full points. For more details check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to prove it explicitly with vector cross products.

Let u be a unit vector normal to the plane of polygon. Then, the n-th normal vector N_n for the vertexes A_n and A_n+1 is

$$N_n = u\times(A_{n}-A_{n+1})$$

where $A_{n}-A_{n+1}$ is the vector of the n-th side.

The sum is then,

$$N_1+N_2+ \>... \>+N_n=u\times(A_{1}-A_2)+u\times(A_{2}-A_3)+\>...\>+u\times(A_{n}-A_1)$$
$$=u\times(A_{1}-A_2 + A_{2}-A_3+...+A_{n}-A_1)=u\times 0=0$$

---

For a particular triangle below

[image]

Along the horizontal direction, you need to show

$$b\sin\gamma = c\sin\beta$$

which is guaranteed by the sine rule.

And, along the vertical direction, you need to show

$$ a = c\cos\beta + b\cos\gamma$$

which is evident from the diagram, i.e. the RHS matches the base length $a$.

Comment: Is there any way to prove this with dot product of the 3 sides of the triangle? We havent gone over cross product and are only supposed to use what we know. Additionally, if this isnt possible can you re write this for the specific triangle situation?

Comment: @smaj - See the diagram and the proof for a triangle.

Comment: OKOKOK I'm starting to get it.....BUT when take the cross product of one of the vectors that make up the side of the triangle (lets call that a for now) with the z vector, how do you know that the result will be a vector perpendicular to a? Again, I know that it is true, but, how??? Mathematically/analytically, not conceptually

Comment: Also is it legal to take the cross product of vector a with the vector that describes the z axis?

Comment: It is the definition of the cross product, that is the crossed vector is perpendicular to the two component vectors. It is perfectly fine to cross product a vector in the z-direction. The cross product is a 3D operation.

Comment: so inorder to get the outward perpendicular to vector a, does it matter which vector in the z direction i need to cross with a? Like, can I cross the vector (0,0,1) or (0,0,2) with a and still get the required outward perpendicular to by vector a (which is the traingle's side)
Basically how would I explain the reason behind the crossing vector a with a vector from the z direction ?

Comment: If you only care about the direction of the normal vector, it does not matter which one to use. But, since you want the same length as a, then you need to use the unit vector (0,0,1).

Comment: @smaj - By definition, $|a\times z |=|a||z|\sin\alpha$, which is why you need a unit vector in z to assure $\alpha =90 $ and the same length.

Comment: @smaj If you don’t like cross products (which does involve embedding the plane into $\mathbb R^3$), you can form an equivalent expression with $2\times2$ determinants.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it very simply using complex numbers: in the *Argand-Cauchy* plane, let $z-1, z_2, \dots,z_n$ be the affixes of the vertices 
$A_1,A_2,\dots ,A_n$ and consider the vectors determined by the sides of the polygon:
$\overrightarrow{A_1A_2}$, with affix $z_2-z_1$, $\overrightarrow{A_2A_32}$, with affix $z_3-z_2$, $\dots$ ,$\overrightarrow{A{n}A_1}$, with affix $z_n-z_1$.

The vector directly orthogonal to vector $\overrightarrow{A_iA_{i+1}}$ has affix $\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}2}\!(z_{i+1}-z_i)$. Thus the sum of these vectors has affix
$$e^{\tfrac{i\pi}2}\bigl((z_2-z_1)+(z_3-z_2)+\dots+(z_n-z_{n-1})+(z_1-z_n)\bigr)=e^{\tfrac{i\pi}2}\cdot 0.$$